# How to update multiple partial views (one main grid and another totals grid)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have two partial views on my main index page with a filter dropdown.  One partial view is for displaying a list of emps and the other is a roll-up for totaling emp.salary, etc.  Currently, I can update my main emp grid via ajax when the filter dropdown is selected.  The issue is that, my roll-up grid needs to be re-calculated each time a new filter is applied to the main emp grid and I'm not sure how to go about that.

Less details view models here is the code:

**Controller: Person/Index()**

```
// GET: /Person/
public ViewResult Index()
{
   IList<Person> ppl = cs = db.Persons.ToList();

   PersonRollup pr= new PersonRollup();            
   foreach (Person p in ppl)
   {
      pr.salary += ii.salary
   }
   PersonViewModel pvm = new PersonViewModel{Persons = ppl, PersonsRollup = pr}
   return View(pvm);
}
```

**View: Person/Index**

```
@model Models.PersonVM>

@Html.ListBox("Filter")  

<div id="PersonRollupGrid">@Html.Partial("_PersonsRollup", Model.PersonsRollup)</div>

<div id="PersonGrid">@Html.Partial("_Persons", Model.Persons)</div>  

@* Filter selected from drop down *@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select").multiselect({
        click: function () {
            $.get('@Url.Action("FilterPersons")', function (data) {
                $('#PersonGrid').html(data);
            });
            // ???????????????????????????????????????????
            //   How can I update the rollup grid here....
            //???????????????????????????????????????????
            }
        });
</script>
```

**Shared View: _Persons**

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Person>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.name</td>
        <td>@item.salary</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Shared View: _PersonsRollup**

```
@model Models.PersonRollup

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>TotalSalary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@model.salary</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Controller: Filter**

```
  public ActionResult FilterPersons(string someFilteredData)
  {
    IList<Person> ppl = cs = db.Persons.Where(/*someFilteredData*/).ToList();

   PersonRollup pr= new PersonRollup();            
   foreach (Person p in ppl)
   {
      pr.salary += ii.salary
   }
   PersonViewModel pvm = new PersonViewModel{Persons = ppl, PersonsRollup = pr}

   return PartialView("_Persons", ppl.Persons);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 //get the filtered viewmodel data
 $.get('@Url.Action("FilterPersons")', function (data) { 
      //pass viewmodel to get rendered view             
      $("#PersonGrid").load("/Person/GetPersonsView"
         data.Persons, function () {
           //callback
      });
      //pass viewmodel to get rendered view       
      $("#PersonRollupGrid").load("/Person/GetPersonsRollUpView",
         data.PersonsRollup, function () {
           //callback
      });

 });


  public ActionResult FilterPersons(string someFilteredData)
  {
       ....
       return JsonResult(pvm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }

  public ActionResult GetPersonsView(Persons persons)
  {   
      return PartialView("_Persons", persons);
  }

  public ActionResult GetPersonsRollUpView(PersonRollup personRollup)
  {   
      return PartialView("_PersonsRollUp", personRollup);
  }
```

Comment: AWESOME! The only issue that I'm running into is when returning the json result back from my call to FilterPersons. return Json(pvm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); I get "Internal Server Error"

Comment: But I'm assuming the internal error has something to do with the properties of my PersonView (that contains the Persons IEnum and PersonsRollup IEnum and that Persons[] collection is a list of domain objects of type Person.

Comment: Yeah, you will need some lightweight DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create another Partial view say _PersonDetails which in turn will have the two partial views:_Persons and _PersonsRoll. The _PersonDetails can be rendered in the Index view. The view will accept the viewModel - PersonViewModel. Inside the _PersonDetails view you can render the _Persons and _PersonsRoll up passing its model objects - Persons, PersonRollUp.
During your Ajax call you load _PersonDetails view from the controller. The children views will be automatically rendered. 
The advantage of this is that you need to just make a single Server call to render two views (which in your case depends on the same viewModel)